# BigQuery how to query partition by month/year when table partitioned by day?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I partitioned a table using the following command on the `date` field and it got partitioned by `day` by default.

```
CREATE TABLE `sales.sales_txn_partition` PARTITION BY DateOfTxn CLUSTER BY SalesPersonID AS (SELECT * FROM `sales.sales_records` WHERE SalesDate IS NOT NULL)
```

[image]

Now, I want to filter based on `year/month` as well in my `WHERE` clause instead of writing the complete date. Is it possible or I'd need to create new partitioned table for year/month separately?

I'm using the following command, nothing works

```
SELECT * FROM `sales.sales_txn_partition` WHERE DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM _PARTITIONTIME), MONTH) = 2018; 
## Doesnt work: Query error: Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONTIME at [3:78]

SELECT * FROM `sales.sales_txn_partition` WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR from DateOfTxn)=2018;
## Works but scans the full table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use direct comparisons?

```
where DateOfTxn >= date('2018-01-01') and
      DateOfTxn < date('2019-01-01')
```

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri . . . I don't know.  I do know that BigQuery is quite sensitive to how partitions are defined.  For instance, if you are joining two tables -- even on the partition key -- the partitions need to be expressed for each table (or at least the last time I checked).